# How to wrap the middle of text instead the last letter

Tags: flutter

I'm attempting to fix a button in my popup, which has an unusual issue with the last letter:

[image]

I need to set "maxLines" to 2, and I'm wondering if there's a method to wrap the text in the middle to make it more readable.

Any suggestions?

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => (),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      elevation: 0,
    ),
    child: const Text(
      "Thisisalongtextwr",
      style: TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 14,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      maxLines: 2,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Did you try with warp widget ?

Comment: @Minato not works because I only have one element "text"

Comment: im not sure if i understand your requirement. it looks like it's in the middle to me. Do you want the size of the text to go smaller to fit into one line when screen is smaller?

Comment: Take a look of the "Thisisalongtextwr", the letter "r" is lonely at the bottom, I would like to know if it's possible to break the text something like this: "Thisisalong- /n textwr" automatically and not the last letter only (Btw, it depend of the screen size, sometimes it fit, sometimes not...)

Comment: oh ok i get it now. wrap is the way to do it, but if you have one element of text there is no way for the compiler to know and understand the words and know where exactly to break it. you'd have to make a list of words and make a compare function to tell the compiler where exactly you want to break it off. Or the other option would be to break the text element into multiple separate text variables based on length

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, please provide your text and explain how you fetch it so i can try find alternative solutions

Answer (score 1):

You have to break your text String into separate strings to let the compiler know where exactly you need the next line to start from, then use a Wrap widget to put them together.

For example:

```
List<String> textList = [
  'This',
  'is',
  'a',
  'long',
  'textwr',
];

Expanded(
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 40,
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      child: Wrap(
        children: [
          for (String text in words)
            Text(
              text,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

[image]

You can use packages or Regex to detect words inside your string and break them. For example, if your string has specific characters like a `'` to help determine where to break the line, you can use regex like this:

```
String myString = "'Thisisalong''textwr'";
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"\('(.*?)'\)");
  List<String> _list =[];
  for (var m in exp.allMatches(myString)) {
    _list.add(m[1].toString());
   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply insert a space in the middle.

You can also insert the special Line Separator character (U+2028) which is invisible but works like a space in the sense that it breaks a word in that spot if needed.

Comment: It depends on the screen size, I can't add a space randomly. I would need to calculate it for each screen size, otherwise...

Comment: You can use the invisible Line Separator every 5 characters or whatever you want. It’s invisible.